# How to properly dispatch an axios delete with react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I am trying to get the state to refresh after a delete request. The correct id is being deleted but it is not refreshing the state at all because the action payload is empty. Below is my current code.

**actions\index.js**

```
...
function deleteCustomerSucceeded(customer){
    return{
        type:"DELETE_CUSTOMER_SUCCEEDED",
        payload:{
           customer
        }
    }
}

export function deleteCustomer(id){
    return(dispatch) =>{
        api.deleteCustomer(id).then((res) => {
            dispatch(deleteCustomerSucceeded(res.data))
        })
    }
...
```

**reducers\index.js**

```
...
    case 'DELETE_CUSTOMER_SUCCEEDED':{
        return{
            ...state,
            customers: state.customers.filter(customer => customer.id !== action.payload)
        }
    }
...
```

**api\index.js**

```
export function deleteCustomer(id){
    return client.delete(`/customers/${id}`)
}
```

**myview.js**

```
  deleteCustomer(){
      let state = {submitted: true}
      this.props.onDeleteCustomer(this.state.customer.id)
      state = {
        ...state,
        customer: this.emptyCustomer,
        deleteCustomerDialog: false
    }
    this.setState(state)
  }
```

Let me know if there needs to be any further clarification or any additional code you may need to see to help answer this question.

Comment: The payload is probably empty because the delete endpoint is not returning any data, thus `res.data` will be empty. What you can do is instead of passing `res.data` as an argument to the `deleteCustomerSucceeded` action creator, you could pass in your `id` parameter: `dispatch(deleteCustomerSucceeded(id))`

Comment: @Kapobajza that helped me resolve this. I thought you has to have the res.data from the success, but now I see that I can do it with res and just pass the data I need to it. After switching stuff out I got it work thank you so much I spent too many hours on why that wasn't working and now the answer seems so obvious in why it was coming back empty. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

After Kapobajza answer I made these changes to my code to make it work.

**reducers\index.js**

```
    case 'DELETE_CUSTOMER_SUCCEEDED':{
        return{
            ...state,
            customers: state.customers.filter(customer => customer.id !== action.payload.id)
        }
         
    }
```

**actions\index.js**

```
function deleteCustomerSucceeded(id){
    return{
        type:"DELETE_CUSTOMER_SUCCEEDED",
        payload:{
           id
        }
    }
}

export function deleteCustomer(id){
    return(dispatch) =>{
        api.deleteCustomer(id).then((res) => {
            dispatch(deleteCustomerSucceeded(id))
        })
    }
}
```